# Details of Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android and I recently learned the advantages of using shared preferences in codes, that is, to save and retain the data even after the app process is killed.

My question is this. How does this concept exactly work? When you consider the finer details, just as local variables are stored in stack, and variables assigned through dynamic memory allocations are stored in heap, how and where are the shared preferences data stored and retained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how and where are the shared preferences data stored and retained?

`SharedPreferences` are stored on internal storage within your application package as `XML` file. So data in SharedPreferences are persisted until you unistall your application or you'll clear application data. When you are reading them, you are reading `XML` file.

And its location is:

```
/data/data/com.your.package/shared_prefs/com.your.package_preferences.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Shared preferences are persistently stores on the internal storage. They are persistent so are preserved between the uses of the application and survive killing the application's process.

When you clear the application data, shared preferences are removed.

You can check more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref